# ¿Consulta con tablas relacionadas?

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de generar una consulta con tablas relacionadas, tengo una llamada depósitos, la cual guarda el id de otras 4 tablas, usuarios, estados, bancos y tipos, pero cuando hago la consulta, únicamente logro traer los id de las otras tablas, y no los nombres, ya tengo ellas las relaciones en los modelos.

Ahora explico mejor el problema, si hago una consulta general, independientemente del usuario que haya hecho el deposito, si logro traer los datos que necesito, el problema es cuando solo quiero traer los depósitos de un usuario en especifico, pues allí solo logro traer los id de las otras tablas, y no los nombres que es lo que me interesa.

De momento tengo mi consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
 public function index()
{

  $depositos = DB::table('depositos')
  ->select('depositos.*','depositos.id as id_deposito', 'depositos.monto','depositos.fechaboleta','depositos.detalles','depositos.observaciones','depositos.created_at','depositos.updated_at','depositos.noboleta')
  ->where( 'id_usuario','=', Auth::id())
  ->join('bancos','bancos.id','=','depositos.id_banco')
  ->join('tipos','tipos.id','=','depositos.id_tipo')
  ->join('estados','estados.id','=','depositos.id_estado')
  ->paginate(5);
  return view('depositos.index', compact('depositos'));

}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al hacer el select estás delimitando la consulta a las columnas especificadas. También mostrará las columnas por las que estás buscando (where). Para que salgan los datos de las otras tablas tienes que especificarlos:

```
public function index()
{
  $depositos = DB::table('depositos')
       ->select('depositos.*', 'bancos.*', 'tipos.*', 'estados.*')
       ->where( 'id_usuario','=', Auth::id())
       ->join('bancos','bancos.id','=','depositos.id_banco')
       ->join('tipos','tipos.id','=','depositos.id_tipo')
       ->join('estados','estados.id','=','depositos.id_estado')
       ->paginate(5);

  return view('depositos.index', compact('depositos'));

}
```

***Editado para ampliar***

Pero si haces este tipo de consulta a la base de datos, no tendrás una Collection de objetos, sino de arrays.

Te devuelve el error: `Undefined property: stdClass::$banco` porque corta con el primer error, pero si continuara también devolvería: `Undefined property: stdClass::$tipo` y `Undefined property: stdClass::$estado`.

Para poder trabajar como lo estás haciendo en la vista tienes que tener definidas las relaciones en el modelo y, luego, hacer la consulta con el modelo:

**Modelo Depósitos**

```
public function banco(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Bancos', 'id_banco');
}

public function tipo(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tipos', 'id_tipo');
}

public function estado(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Estados', 'id_estado');
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function index()
    {
        $depositos = Depositos::where('id_usuario', '=', Auth::id())
            ->paginate(5);

        return view('depositos.index', compact('depositos'));
    }
```

**Y en la vista:**
Aquí ya puedes usar `$deposito->banco->nombre`, `$deposito->tipo->tipo` y `$deposito->estado->estado` porque `$deposito` es un objeto con sus relaciones, también objetos con propiedades y métodos.

```
@foreach($depositos as $deposito)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $deposito->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->noboleta }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->monto }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->banco->nombre }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->tipo->tipo }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->fechaboleta }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->detalles }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->observaciones }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->created_at }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->estado->estado }}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->updated_at }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: no me funciona, me muestra solo los ID de las columnas

Comment: Gracias me has salvado, estaba haciendo mal la consulta en el controlador al usar DB::where y no Depositos::where, que es exactamente como tú dices, las relaciones en el modelo ya las tenía.

Answer (score 0):

así intento mostrar los datos, pero me da el siguiente error

```
<td>{{ $deposito->id}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->noboleta}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->monto}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->banco->nombre}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->tipo->tipo}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->fechaboleta}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->detalles}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->observaciones}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->estado->estado}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->updated_at}}</td>
    <td>
```

Undefined property: stdClass::$banco